# Excel VBA Select Cell Ranges

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have the following code, but I get a "Object Required" error on line `Set CellRange = wks.Range(srange).Select`.

I have tried many things, but cannot figure it out.  I want to set background colors on a selected range based on a particular cell value.

```
Function RowColor()
    Application.Volatile
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim FirstRow As Integer
    Dim CellRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    FirstRow = 6

    'Loop through each row
    ScreenUpdating = False

    For x = FirstRow To LastRow
     Let srange = "A" & x & ":" & "Z" & x
    Set CellRange = wks.Range(srange).Select


     Select Case wks.Cells(x, "R").Value

      Case "O"
            CellRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)

      Case "D"
            CellRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
      Case "C"
        If wks.Cells(x, "Y") >= 0 Then
            CellRange.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        Else
            CellRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
      Case "W"
            CellRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
     End Select
    Next x
    ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: Remove the `.Select` on the end.

Comment: @WaiHaLee If the OP wants an actual answer I will.  They got down voted not for "Stealing" my answer but because they are comments not answers.  If they put their comments were they belong and delete their answers, they would get their rep points back.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, which has gotten too much acclaim, change this:

```
Set CellRange = wks.Range(srange).Select
```

To:

```
Set CellRange = wks.Range(srange)
```

Remove the `.Select`.  One does not set a range object using the `.Select` funstion.  Simply set the range object to the range.

Answer (score -3):

Scott in the comments is correct: remove the .Select at the end.

Selecting cells does not return anything.